# Student Registration system

Tags: java

Course:
Each course has a name, credit, code, prerequisite list (array or arraylist of other courses) 
A corresponding course list (course that are equivalent to that course, if a student has taken and passed an equivalent course as prerequisite she can take the course)

Am i on the right way?

```
package registrationsystem;
import java.util.*;
public class Course {

    private String name;
    private double credit;
    private String code;



    protected Course(String name,double credit,String code,String[][]prerequisities,String[][]corresponding){
        this.name=name;
        this.credit=credit;
        this.code=code;


    }





}
```

I have also post my main class:

```
    String [] prerequisities={"MIS131","TRM101"};
    String [] corresponding={"TRM256","MIS131"};



    Course c1=new Course("IntroductiontoJavaProgramming",3,"MIS131",prerequisities,corresponding);
    Course c2=new Course("ObjectOriented",4,"MIS132",prerequisities,corresponding);

courses.add(c1);
    courses.add(c2);
    courses.add(c3);
```

Is that right?

Comment: Yes! Although your arrays do not need to be 2 dimensional : just write `String[] prerequisites`. They should probably be `Course`s rather than `String`s btw.

Comment: Curious that `prerequisities` is a 2D array. Make sure you have your data fields for everything, otherwise passing them in the constructor is useless.

Comment: i also post my main class,can you please look at it

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run your code? If yes, post them. If not, your question is off topic here. If you want to improve existing code you can post it on [codereview.se], in any case your question is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks close to me! I would recommend using a String[] for both "prerequisites" and "corresponding".  Two-Dimensional arrays shouldn't be used in this case. You will also need to make a member variable for these data (just as you have done with string, credit and code).

Comment: yes but for example MIS131 is a prerequisite for MIS132,but if i create one dimensional prerequisite array how is it possible to match this two lessons?